# External content won't load in iframe in Safari

Tags: htaccess, directory, iframe, browser-compatibility

I'm trying to load external content into an iframe, & it is working in Chrome & Firefox, but it won't load in Safari. In Safari I get the error message:

> Refused to display 'my_content' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

I think the issue may be that my WordPress install is in a subdirectory:

- WordPress Address (URL): https://example.com/wp
- Site Address (URL): https://example.com

The header for my external content includes the following:

```
 X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
 Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com
 X-Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com
```

This article lists a number of possible reasons for the issue with Safari & SAMEORIGIN https://halfelf.org/2018/safari-and-sameorigin/. I don't have any extra X-Frame-Options in my .htaccess file, so I'm wondering if the issue is related to my WordPress install being located in a subdirectory. Is there a workaround for this? Or is this caused by something else?

Comment: And the "external content" is on the same or different _hostname_?

Comment: @MrWhite It's on a different _hostname_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone with much more knowledge about this fixed it for me. I'm posting the answer here in case it can help someone else:

> We have made some changes and implemented a way to allow [external
> content] to be displayed using the Content-Security-Policy directives,
> instead X-Frame-Options. X-Frame-Options used to be deprecated, and
> was un-deprecated recently with any CSP directives superceding all
> X-Frame-Option directives, as per [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034).
>
> Please note however, there were many issues with Safari iFrames
> support, as it does not fully comply with specifications (contrary to
> what it claims).
>
> After a thorough investigation, Safari supports CSF from version 10+
> (latest is 12).
>
> - However, support is only available if X-Frame-Options is undefined.
> - If X-Frame-Options is defined, then that super-cedes CSF, contrary to MDN specs.
> - Safari and WebKit-based browsers do not support X-Frame-Option’s allow-from directive, preventing specific sites from being granted
>   access.
> - And as such, does not support multiple domains for whitelisting.
>
> We are now using Content-Security-Policy directives to dictate iFrame
> whitelisting, without X-Frame-Option directives.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
> ```

By itself (and in older browsers) this would certainly deny access. However, in compliant browsers you would expect the `Content-Security-Policy:` header to override this.

Assuming you have control over this external content, have you tried setting this header to:

```
 X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com
```

Or

```
 X-Frame-Options: sameorigin, allow-from https://example.com
```

(Although Safari may not support the `allow-from` directive.)

Or, removing this header altogether?

> I'm wondering if the issue is related to my WordPress install being located in a subdirectory.

I don't see how having WordPress installed in a subdirectory would have anything to do with this?